# jQuery populate text input field with fileinput file name

Tags: jquery

i need to populate simple text input field with name of selected file name(in fileinput).

So if I choose to upload file Picture.jpg I have to populate input field with Picture.jpg text.

My file input fields

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file m-r-10">
  <span class="fileinput-new"><?= __('Select file') ?></span>
  <span class="fileinput-exists"><?= __('Change file') ?></span>
  <input type="file" name="user_file" id="selected-file" onchange="getval(this);">
  </span>
  <span class="fileinput-filename"><?= __('No file') ?></span>
<div>
```

I want to save valu in text input

```
<?= $this->Form->input('name', ['id'=> 'name', class' => 'form-control']); ?>
```

Solution

```
<script>
function getval(sel) {
    $('#name').val(sel.value);
}
</script>
```

I can not read value from selected file $('#selected-file').val() - result is empty.

So how can I then read file name?

Thx

Comment: `I can not read value from selected file $('#selected-file').val() - result is empty.` How have you attempted to read it? It should work fine, assuming you hook to the `change` event of the field

Comment: Soory, it was my mistake, I was using change on <span> not on <input> tag